# 4chan: Can't find node with xml_find_all and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape 4chan for their infinite wisdom, but I am having trouble utilising rvest w/ xml. I am used too using BS4 in Python, so forgive me if this is obvious.

Here I am trying to capture the title of a thread:

```
soup <- read_html('https://boards.4chan.org/pol/catalog')

soup %>% html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml_find_all(".//id[contains(@class, 'teaser')]") %>% 
  html_text()
```

[See attached,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWR8y.png) I think I have pointed the code to the right direction, but I get 'character(0)' in my output.

Any help is appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the page loads dynamically, so you would need `RSelenium` instead of `rvest`.

For instance, it seems to work with this code:

```
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://boards.4chan.org/pol/catalog")

# scroll down a bit and wait some seconds so as to ensure the loading of the page
remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");")) 
Sys.sleep(5)

# fetch the html code
soup <- remDr$getPageSource()
soup <- xml2::read_html(soup[[1]])

# obtain the titles
thread_titles <- soup %>% html_nodes("#threads div.teaser > b") %>% 
  html_text()

# exit
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

The vector `thread_titles` then contains 127 titles.

I hope it's fine that I used the CSS selector (`#threads div.teaser > b`) instead of xpath?

Comment: Thanks anpami, worked a charm. You're a legend.